# Specifying .class files as resources and make them copied to output (bin) folder - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, buildpath

How to make eclipse treat a directory containing class files as a resource directory and make it copied to the output folder (bin) ?

My project Structure is like this

```
src
  com
    package1
       all source files (.java)
       image files
    package2
       some dependent class files (.class)
bin
  com
    package1
       generated .class files for source files
       image files
    package2
       (empty)
```

In eclipse I have specified exculsion filter to exclude the `src\com\package2` from source folder list. And I have added the absolute path to src folder in buildpath, so the classes in `src\com\package2` are available to build the source files.

Now I want to export the whole set of classes (generated and referenced) into JAR file. For that I need to have the `src\com\package2` classes in `bin\com\package2` folder which is now empty. Is there any way I can make eclipse treat the class files in `src\com\package2` as resource files (like images in `src\com\package1`) and get them copied to `bin\com\package2`?

PS: Runnable JAR is not an option as I have so many libraries referenced.

Comment: I don't know a way to configure the export in eclipse as you describe. But maybe an simple ANT-Script will do? You can copy all desired recources into one folder and call the "jar" Ant task.

Comment: I think there's an easier way than this, and it won't require you to treat .class files as resources.  Is it possible to ask Eclipse to "create jar" and specify a root directory?  You can with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new folder in root of project. Move your class files to that folder and add it as a 'class folder' in Java Build path. Now while exporting the jar you can select the class folder and you will get what you want in the jar.

Comment: You just need a separate folder that can be referenced in the Java build path. It does not have to be in the root of the project. For example, '/src/classes/com/package2' would work just as well as '/classes/com/package2'. Just make sure that you add '/src/classes' to the build path and not '/src/classes/com/package2' so that the folders get added to the JAR.

Comment: Faron, you are right. I gave answer which solves his problem without mixing source and class files. Ideally the class files should have gone to jar file with version info.